# java.sql.SQLException: Could not find stored procedure

Tags: java, jdbc, callable-statement, java-stored-procedures

```
[dbo].[GetUserCredentials]
   @Company varchar(255),
   @SchedType varchar(255),
   @ShiftHours varchar(255),
   @UserRole varchar(255),
   @UserDesc varchar(255),
   @UserOwner varchar(255)
select ... from ... where ...
```

Stored Procedure ^

java code that calls the stored procedure

```
CallableStatement statement = con.prepareCall("{call GetUserCredentials}");
statement.execute();
```

Result

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not find stored procedure 'GetUserCredentials'.

Comment: are you connecting with right schema, which database are you using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that your stored procedure have missing input parameters, add "?" (number of input parameters) in the prepareCall statement
eg.

```
stmt = con.prepareCall("{call insertEmployee(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            stmt.setString(2, name);
            stmt.setString(3, role);
            stmt.setString(4, city);
            stmt.setString(5, country);
```

look this [article](https://www.journaldev.com/2502/callablestatement-in-java-example) to understand it better

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that is what I did. I edited the stored procedure and added the set string to the code